# unable create ondrive with csom

Tags: provisioning, onedrive, csom

I create my users via code with csom since months. I assign them a license and create one drive to fill with a structure of folders and shares points. It worked well, but in recent weeks provisioning onedrive stops working. This means that the command Csom CreatePersonalSiteEnqueueBulk is executed without error, however, the users onedrive is not done and then it is impossible to create folders.

If i log onto office 365 with a user account and create is ondrive i can use csom code to create folder and so on.

Here is the code executed without error. (48h after onedrive is not create)

```
    _context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

     _context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials (Email, GetSecurePassword);

    ProfileLoader _profileLoader = ProfileLoader.GetProfileLoader (_context);

    _profileLoader.CreatePersonalSiteEnqueueBulk (emailIDs);

    _profileLoader.Context.ExecuteQuery ();
```

The questions are:

- Where can you follow the requests put in queue for creating onedrives in Office 365 administration interface ?
- Does the methode change ?
- Can we use a parameter in office 365 administration interface to force creation of user onedrive when user account is created in in Office 365?
- Is there a comdlet to create one drive ?

thank you

Sly